# C# console app template that can call WinRT apis?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

The templates I found give me this error

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Windows' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Searching leads me to this link which describes how to add WinRT apis for WPF apps

https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/#vZiZ96PlZUqTduts.97

There are several nuget packages, and I am confused about which one I should be using
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.CsWinRT/
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.Ref/
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts/

The last one gets be the furthest (it can find the windows namespace)

```cs
var stream = new Windows.Storage.Streams.InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
```

> error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Storage' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Are you using .NET Framework or .NET Core/5/6/7+

Comment: @SimonMourier I was trying both. I got .NET Core to work using this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/tools/sdk-errors/netsdk1130

Comment: Yes for .NET core you just have to use  a TFM with Windows in it (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance) and do nothing else. For .NET Framework, you must just add the "Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts" nuget package (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance#earlier-versions-of-net-install-the-microsoftwindowssdkcontracts-nuget-package)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Default package management format` was set to `Packages.Config` and I had to change it to `PackageReference` before installing `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts` as instructed by the link Simon gave me

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance#earlier-versions-of-net-install-the-microsoftwindowssdkcontracts-nuget-package